# how do i deal with anti-forgery token in angular2

Tags: asp.net, angular

I have an app that uses an angular2 frontend and an asp.net core web api backend. My controller methods on the web api has the validate anti-forgery token filter. How can i set my requests from my angular2 service to have valid tokens when making the requests. Below is a samply of my current setup, but i do not know how to add the tokens.

```
export class fileUpload
{
  private serverUrl= "http://localhost:55812/";
  private headers = new Headers([{ 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }, { 'Accept': '*/*' }]);
  private request;


  constructor(private http:Http){}

  //function to upload image for upload module
  upload(data:any):Promise<any>
  {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', data);

    return this.http.post(this.serverUrl+"face/post/",formData,{headers: this.headers})
      .toPromise()
        .then(response => response)
        .catch(error => error);
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `{'X-XSRF-TOKEN': 'your_xsrf_token_value'}` to the `headers`?

Comment: It does not work for me

Comment: Where is your front end app hosted? is that asp.net core web app or is it something else?

Comment: the front end is an angular2 app using the asp.net core angular2 template